# Layout looks different on devices

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi My app looks different on different devices. I use Samsung Galagy S2 as my testing device, but when I tried install app to another device Samsung Galaxy Note 3.

Display resolution: 
Samsung galaxy S2: 800x480(hdp)
Samsung galaxz Note 3: 1920x1080(xxhdp)

My app looks on:
Samsung galaxy S2 like [THIS](http://www.fastimages.eu/images/hdp.png)
Samsung galaxy Note 3 like [THIS](http://www.fastimages.eu/images/xhdp.png)

As you can see in first picture it looks good but on Note 3 there are a lot of empty space at bottom of app. All images I use are xxhdp and hdp too. The problem is in gap between buttons. I set it in dp so I thought in every device it will look like in my phone. But on galaxy S2 and galaxy Note 3 it looks same gap.

This is my layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutHA"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutHA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/infoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/info"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/facebookButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/infoButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/facebook"
             />

         <Button
            android:id="@+id/emailButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:minWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/facebookButton"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/email"
             />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/animal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/animal_pic"
        android:text="Animals" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/insect"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/insect"
        android:text="Insects" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nature"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/nature"
        android:text="Nature" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/people"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/people"
        android:text="People" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gun"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gun"
        android:text="Guns" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: both images are same.

Comment: No I have 260x260 in xxhdp and 130x130 in hdp

Comment: i am saying that images that you have uploaded are same.

Comment: It happens because you fix the layout_height of vertical buttons to the same value (55dp). In xxhdpi the device height is longer so there are a lot of empty space in the bottom of your app

Comment: you could use a linearlayout with the attribute weight

Comment: but dp in HDP device means different pixels than dp in XXHDP ... or not?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't mean your layout will fit the device screen

Comment: `I have 260x260 in xxhdp and 130x130 in hdp` ... which is as expected. 260 is the double of 130, as well as xxhdpi (480 dpi) is the double as hdpi (240 dpi).

Comment: @user3934048 Instead of using fixed width and height, use `wrap_content` and see what happens. Since you correctly sized the drawable resources (at least for xxhdpi and hdpi), you should go fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the LinearLayout to cover all your vertical buttons and set the layout_height of this LinearLayout to match_parent.Inside this LinearLayout, set the layout_weight for each button to same value(ex:1) and layout_height to 0dp

Answer (score 0):

You have to manage height and width with dimen.create a dimen for values-v11,values-v14,values-sw600dp values layout and set height and width based on layout and check.

Answer (score 0):

I also had same issue, but i solved it by creating 3 different layouts for same activity.

1. layout_large(for xhdp layouts)
2. layout_xlarge(for xxhdp layouts)
3. layout(for xhdp layouts)

You dont need to bother about assigning preferred layout, android device select the layout which is most suitable for their screen. My answer seem to be extra work but its most preferrable if you want to have consistent view on different screen size. Read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).